# Textfield as input in average function

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, func

I recently wanted to code an Average-Calculator. 
My plan was to build a `UITextField` in which you can type Numbers separated by commas... By pressing the 'Calculate' button the App should calculate the Average of the Numbers above and give them out by setting a labeltext to the average.
So I wrote my average function and received this error message:

> Can not convert value of type 'UITextField' to expected element type 'Double'.

This is my Code:

```
@IBOutlet var Input: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var Output: UILabel!
@IBAction func Calculate(sender: AnyObject) {

    var grades:[Double] = [Input]
    func average(nums: [Double]) -> Double {

        var total = 0.0
        for grade in nums{

            total += Double(grade)
        }

        let gradesTotal = Double(nums.count)
        let average = total/gradesTotal
        return average
    }

    let Average = average(grades)

    Output.text = "Average: \(Average)"
}
```

Can you help me with my idea? 
Is there a better way to get an input?

Comment: use 'Double(Input.text)' . You are right now assigning textfield object to double

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use lower camel case for variables...

In this line:

```
var grades:[Double] = [Input]
```

`Input` is an instance of `UITextField`, so you are trying to assign a single-element `Array<UITextField>` to `Array<Double>`. You see you cannot do such sort of things.

If you want to accept a text which contains *Numbers separated by commas*, you need to explicitly convert the `text` to `[Double]`.

To simplify, let's just ignore the `nil` or non-numeric values.
Then you need to change your code as:

```
@IBOutlet var input: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var output: UILabel!
@IBAction func calculate(sender: AnyObject) {

    var grades: [Double] = (input.text ?? "").componentsSeparatedByString(",").flatMap{Double($0)}
    func average(nums: [Double]) -> Double {

        var total = 0.0
        for grade in nums{

            total += Double(grade)
        }

        let gradesTotal = Double(nums.count)
        let average = total/gradesTotal
        return average
    }

    let averageValue = average(grades)

    output.text = "Average: \(averageValue)"
}
```

The basic idea of this line:

```
var grades: [Double] = (input.text ?? "").componentsSeparatedByString(",").flatMap{Double($0)}
```

is well-described in Lu_'s answer. Mine is just a little safer version.

---

(Addition)
Some explanation about safety:

`UITextField`s property `text` is of type `String?`, so you should think it can be nil. Giving a default value for nil with `??` operator.

And using `Double($0)!` may crash your app, as `Double($0)` will return nil for non-numeric strings.

**Writing these reminded me one more crash case.**

When `gradesTotal` == 0, the code above will crash with division by zero.

(The `default` value does not work well for "safety" in the code above...)

So, one more step ahead to safety:

```
@IBAction func calculate(sender: AnyObject) {

    var grades: [Double] = (input.text ?? "").componentsSeparatedByString(",").flatMap{
        Double($0.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(.whitespaceCharacterSet()))
    }
    func average(nums: [Double]) -> Double? {

        var total = 0.0
        for grade in nums{

            total += Double(grade)
        }

        let gradesTotal = Double(nums.count)
        if gradesTotal > 0 {
        let average = total/gradesTotal
            return average
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    if let averageValue = average(grades) {
        output.text = "Average: \(averageValue)"
    } else {
        output.text = "Average not available"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reporting. Please remember this answer is improved with cooperation of the Stack Overflow community. And hope your experience will help other community members. Good luck for you and for your app.

Comment: I dont know why but when I launch the app now it breaks at
@IBOutlet var input: UITextField!
It worked perfectly but know it breaks every time... I don't think that I changed something... I even deleted the code so it should only lode the View without any functionality but it broke as well...

Comment: Sometimes, Xcode projects can be in sort of inconsistent state, breaks here and there, seemingly connected `@IBOutlet`s & `@IBAction`s are not actually connected... Clear all breakpoints, disconnect all  `@IBOutlet`s & `@IBAction`s and reconnect them. And clean-build after re-starting your Xcode. If those such things do not help, you better post a new question with describing your issue more precisely.

Comment: Ok I wrote the Project again and now everything works fine :) 
I even loaded it on my iPhone so now!

Answer (score 6):

You need to separate numbers to get that array if you do that: 
[image]

you can pass "doubles" array to your average function

code to copypaste :)

```
var str = "1,2,3,4,5,6"

let stringsWithNumbers = str.componentsSeparatedByString(",")

let doubles = stringsWithNumbers.map { Double($0)! }
```

Comment: Nice! This addresses both problems in the question.

Comment: accidently removed comment, sorry, just wanted to quote. Code added thanks for reminding about that.

Comment: You're welcome.  I try to free up obsolete comments as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is using `Double(Input.text)` instead of `[Input]`. Right now, you were trying to convert a `UITextField` to a double, which causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
let textInput = txtInputView.text;
let components = textInput.componentsSeparatedByString(",");
let sum = 0.0;
for txt in components
{
     sum = sum + Double(txt);
}

let avg = sum / components.count;
print(avg)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code if someone is interested :)

```
@IBOutlet var input: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var output: UILabel!
@IBAction func calculate(sender: AnyObject) {

    var grades: [Double] = (input.text ?? "").componentsSeparatedByString(",").flatMap{
        Double($0.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(.whitespaceCharacterSet()))
    }
    func average(nums: [Double]) -> Double? {

        var total = 0.0
        for grade in nums{

            total += Double(grade)
        }

        let gradesTotal = Double(nums.count)
        if gradesTotal > 0 {
            let average = total/gradesTotal
            return average
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    if let averageValue = average(grades) {
        output.text = "Average: \(averageValue)"
    } else {
        output.text = "Average not available"
    }

}

@IBAction func userTappedCalculate(sender: AnyObject) { view.endEditing(true)
}
```

I added the line `@IBAction func userTappedCalculate(sender: AnyObject) { view.endEditing(true)
    }` to close the input TextField when you tap calculate...